# Retrieving data that is not the concern of the Domain - DDD

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Certain portions of my software don't really fit within a domain but just improve the experience of the software.  A good example of this is an `Employee` or `Product` photo, essentially it has no meaning in the domain and business logic, but I still need access to it.

The photo could be stored as a `byte[]` in the persistence layer or in my case a `Uri` that merely references the photo in some other isolated storage.

What would one do practicing DDD in this case?  does it really make sense to keep a property on the `Employee` or `Product` aggregates like:

```
public Uri PhotoUri { get { return this._photoUri; } }
```

Or is there another approach I haven't heard of yet that makes more sense?

Comment: IMO a photo is part of the Domain, it's part of the concept definition. It might not be used for anything, but it's a part of it.

Comment: That's if you consider the domain to encompass the design of the software itself.  I was under the impression the domain is modelled on the business and its transactions/services only.  Then, IMO, it seems a photo does not fit within the domain as a photo is largely a usability/experience concern.  I guess its just one of those "things"

Comment: Though users will be able to set their own `Employee/UserAccount` photo's but again its a concern of the software UX not really the business..

Comment: I think it would be fine to have a photoUri in Employee. But if there are too many of them, you may consider split them into another bounded context. Once we took this approach when building a hotel booking system. There were too many descriptive properties on Hotel and they makes no sense of booking rule. We ended up having two contexts: hotel-content and hotel-booking. The former one was built using simple CRUD as it was used mainly for query and simple-form editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most businesses, they store employee photos as part of an employee information like their first name. It is commonly used in IDs.

I would ask the business people if they store employee photos, used as identification or additional information, if they answer Yes then it is part of the domain.

If the business people can understand it without talking about the software then it is perfectly fine to put it in your domain. Just think of it as complementary information.